# empty response on detectintent with text

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am using a dialog flow bot. The user sends the requests to the bot and the bot sends the response with the fulfillment text. After answering some questions, I quit the bot.
After 15min or so when I call the bot again through the triggering word, it is sending the empty response. Is this due to a session timeout? 
Please help me in solving the issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Please help me.. @Prisoner

Comment: Please consider adding screenshots/code of fulfillment so that we can get a clear view of what the problem is!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577005/unable-to-handle-multiple-fulfillment-responses         This is the exact code I used @SairajSawant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to handle multiple fulfillment responses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577005/unable-to-handle-multiple-fulfillment-responses)

Comment: The problem with handling multiple responses is solved when we trigger a bot for the first time and sending requests and receiving responses.  But once the bot is closed and opened again after some time, we are getting empty responses. @SairajSawant